# Percentage of nodes by label in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nodes

How can I get the percentage of nodes by labes in Neo4j?

It should be something like this?:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH COUNT(*) As total
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)--()
WITH DISTINCT count(labels(n)) as c, labels(n) as l
RETURN (c/total)*100, l;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get this info is via the count store, and [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_meta_graph) has the easiest means to get access to this all at once:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD nodeCount, labels
WITH toFloat(nodeCount) as nodeCount, labels
UNWIND keys(labels) as label
RETURN label, labels[label] as count, round(labels[label] / nodeCount * 100) as percentage
```

Keep in mind that since nodes can be multi-labeled, your percentages will likely exceed 100%.